# Why is my fields different in handleChange?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why are my 2 console.log different ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-colden-ib87m?file=/src/App.js

value is ok but login misses one letter every time.

turn 1: value is "a" when login is ""

turn 2: value is "ab" when login is "a"

etc ...

thanks for help !

Comment: Hey, could you try 'onkeyup' event instead of 'change'?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: if you provide sandbox code, It will help more

Comment: there isn't enough code to reproduce your issue, but my guess is that you are assuming that `setForm` is instantaneous, which it isn't, so `form` still holds its previous value.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-colden-ib87m?file=/src/App.js here it is.

So how can it be instantaneous ?

Comment: It can't. React state updates are asynchronous. They are enqueued during the render cycle, batch processed between render cycles, and available during the next render cycle. Is there something other than log the next state value that you are *really* trying to do?

Comment: Yes, i'd like to check if the input is good or flase (with regex for mail for example)
So i need to have tu current state to be updated when i send it to my checkMailFunction().

Maybe i miss something ?

Comment: You can either check the input value *before* updating state, or use an `useEffect` hook to check form state *after* it has updated. If your issue *isn't* react state synchronicity then please update with a more complete code example and what isn't working and click reopen.

Comment: I updated the post, im going to try to use useEffect then but i don't use it yet, i'm new in react hooks